# Stretching a fixed width div background to the side of the broswer window?

Tags: html, css

Imagine a page with the basic structure as below. The main question is how do I get the .left background to extend all the way to the left side of the window, and the .right to extend to the right side? Both need to remain fixed width.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>blah</header>
        <article>doodle doo</article>
        <div class="left">Left stuff with blue background</div>
        <div class="right">Right stuff with red background</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
        <footer>deedle dee</footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
header{
    background-color:grey;
}
.left{
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    background-color:blue;
}
.right{
    width:200px;
    float:right;
    background-color:red;
 }
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
footer{
    background-color:#DDD;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6gfyp6yc/)

The basic idea is the same as [this page](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/full-width-bars/index.html), but you might notice that the page scrolls a loooong way to the right - the cut off doesn't actually work.

Comment: In this case, they should stay the same height.

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved this with `display: table` and pseudo elements.

The basics of this solution:

- The wrapper `.content` is made `display: table` and given `position: fixed` to allow its "cells" to have your fixed width. Provide spacing ,if required, with `border-spacing: unit size;`
- `.left` and `.right` are given `display: table-cell`
- `.content:before` and `.content:after` provide pseudo columns (also with `display: table-cell`) to space out the background.

[Have an example!](http://jsbin.com/jedov/3/edit)

HTML

```
<header></header>
<article></article>
<div class="content">
  <div class="column left"></div>
  <div class="column right"></div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0
}

html,body {
  height:100%
}

.content {
  display:table;
  table-layout:fixed;
  height:100%;
  width:100%
}

header {
  background-color:grey;
  height:20px;
  width:500px;
  margin:0 auto
}

article {
  height:20px;
  width:500px;
  margin:0 auto
}

.column {
  display:table-cell;
  width:200px;
  vertical-align: top
}

.left {
  height:100%;
  background:blue
}

.content:before,.content:after {
  display:table-cell;
  content:'';
  background:blue;
  height:100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left:10%
}

.content:after {
  background:red;
  padding-right:10%
}

.right {
  background-color:red
}

footer {
  background-color:#DDD;
  text-align:center;
  height:50px
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1) Put your `left` and `right` elements into another container:

```
<div class="container">
    <header>blah</header>
    <article>doodle doo</article>
</div>

<div class="container2">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="text">Left stuff with blue background</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="text">Right stuff with red background</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer>deedle dee</footer>
```

2) The `container2` width is `100%`, let the `left` and `right` to be `50%`:

```
.left {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    background-color:blue;
}

.right {
    width:50%;
    float:right;
    background-color:red;
}
```

3) The `text` element on your both columns, should be `200px`:

```
.text {
    width: 200px;
}

.left .text {
    float: right;
}

.right .text {
    float: left;
}
```

[**Working jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6gfyp6yc/14/).